# UIPopoverController frame overlapping its contentView's UINavigationBar

Tags: uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Any idea how to shift the navbar view so I have the expected padding? It looks like the popover frame is overlapped on the nav bar's top, left and right side.

This is my nav controller in a popover controller derived from the app's root splitViewController. It's an issue on < iOS 5.1

[image: UIPopoverController's frame covering its content's navigation bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the custom `UINavigationBar` styling when in a `UIPopoverController`. I'll post the implementation when it's ready.

Update

So this is a funny one. iOS 4.x and iOS 5.0 use a real, genuine popover, that is the floating popover. Custom navigation bars don't work in this popover (`navBar setBackgroundImage` in iOS 5.0 and the category `drawRect` override in iOS 4.x).

However, 5.1 uses more of a "slideover," where the custom navbar works nicely. It's a much cleaner design actually.

Anyway, my point is that now I need to remove the custom navBar formatting only when in portrait AND the OS is less than 5.1. Normally, you'd want to use `respondsToSelector` in lieu of manually figuring out an OS version. That doesn't work in this case.

Still working on the iOS 4.x fix, but here's iOS 5.0:

In my `appDelete`, where I set up the custom navBar:

```c
//iOS 5.x:
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

//iOS 4.x:
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}
@end
```

I set up an observer in `didFinishLaunching`:

```c
//start orientation notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

```c
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (version < 5.1)
    {
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
        {
            if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
            {
                [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
                [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            }
        }
    }
}
```